# How to use Linq join on non key field

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Here is a simplified example

```
public class Book
{
    public string BookId
    public string AuthorName

}

public class Author
{
    public string Name
}

public class BookWithAuthor
{
    public Book Book;
    public Author Author;
}
```

For the sake of this example it is not possible to give Author an Id and use this as the foreign key.

```
List<Book> books = _unitOfWork.BookRepo.Get.ToList();
List<Author> authors= _unitOfWork.AuthorRepo.Get.ToList();
```

I am trying to write a LINQ join on Author.Name/Book.AuthorName fields and return a List of BookWithAuthor. All my attempts so far failed usually to do with "join parameters could not be determined..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
List<Book> books = _unitOfWork.BookRepo.Get.ToList();
List<Author> authors= _unitOfWork.AuthorRepo.Get.ToList();
List<BookWithAuthor> lst = 
    (from c in books
    join d in authors on new {Aname = c.AuthorName } equals new {Aname = d.Name } into cd
    from tcd in cd.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new BookWithAuthor
    {
        Book = c,
        Author = tcd
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var results = _unitOfWork.BookRepo.Get
    .Join(_unitOfWork.AuthorRepo.Get,
        book => book.AuthorName,
        author => author.Name,
        (book, author) => new BookWithAuthor
        {
            Book = book,
            Author = author
        })
    .ToList();
```